# disable "antivirus protection expired" message windows 10

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, malwarebytes

I installed malwarebytes on to my computer to scan a drive,
after the free trial expired(which I wasn't even using in the first place) windows has been giving me this message at some set interval. 
[image]

I would rather keep malwarebytes installed for convenience(in case I need to scan another drive or file), is there any way I can disable this message?
perhaps using the group policy editor or changing a registry value?

Comment: See this page...https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/configure-notifications-windows-defender-antivirus

Comment: You are better of uninstalling, this will turn on Windows Defender, which you can use to scan anything using the right click menu.

Comment: Moab thanks, could have sworn I looked through that
I'll update if turning off enhanced notifications does the trick

Comment: Windows giveth and Windows taketh away, no telling what options disappear in the next build.

Comment: So the solution to this problem is to switch from Malwarebytes Professional back to the free version, from within Malwarebytes.  You might not have realized you switch modes, by starting a trial, but the free edition of Malwarebytes does not cause the behavior you are experiencing.